# Returning/printing 0-number python

Tags: python

Is there a format function in python that turn for example 4 to 04 but 10 not in 010.

The idea is that all numbers under 10 are represented by 0and then the number.

Already thanks a lot.

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

The regular formatting with `%` supports leading zeros with `%0xd` where `x` is the total number of digits:

```
>>> print("%02d" % 4)
04
>>> print("%02d" % 10)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a `string` as Python does not allow you to have `integers` with leading `0s`. As if we define one, we get an error:

```
>>> a = 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 09
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

So the way we can achieve this is to first convert to a `string` and then use `.zfill`:

```
def pad(n, l):
    return str(n).zfill(l)
```

and some tests:

```
>>> pad(4, 2)
'04'
>>> pad(10, 2)
'10'
>>> pad(67, 20)
'00000000000000000067'
```

---

On the other hand, if you only want to pad one-digit `integers` to two-digit `string`, then you could use a `ternary` expression:

```
def pad2(n):
    s = str(n)
    return "0" + s if len(s) < 2 else s
```

and some tests again:

```
>>> pad2(4)
'04'
>>> pad2(10)
'10'
```